# Get from html page only images, br and p- tags with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I want to extract from a html page only `<p>, <br> and image tags`

When I extract only `<p>` tags I'm doing the following:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (HtmlNode node in descriptionDiv.SelectNodes("//p"))
{
  sb.Append(node.InnerText);
}
```

but I also need img and br tags, if I'll repeat this method one after another then I'll lose their order. How can I extract them in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to retrieve descendant nodes and filter them with Where clause.

```
foreach (var node in descriptionDive
            .DescendantNodes()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "p" || x.Name == "br" || x.Name == "img" ))
{
  sb.Append(node.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can keep using Xpath in the following way :

```
var xpath = "//*[self::a or self::br or self::img]";
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath))
{
   sb.Append(node.InnerText);            
}
```